# How to make 3 column Xamarin.Forms FlexLayout with expanding center column and variable width left/right columns?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a `FlexLayout` in Xamarin.Forms that will allow me to have the left and right columns be a variable width, and have the center column (and its contents) fill the remaining space and be centered on the screen.

Here is my current code, and here is what it's producing. Notice that "**CENTER TEXT**" in blue is centered within its `StackLayout`, but the `StackLayout` is not centered on the screen since the left and right columns have different widths.

Is `FlexLayout` a good choice for this, or should I use `Grid` or something else? Ideally, each column will expand to fit its content, with the center column's content being centered on the screen.

Note that the contents of each column is dynamic, so the widths of the left and right columns is also dynamic.

Thank you!

**Code:**

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="titleBar" 
            MinimumHeightRequest="40"
            Padding="10"
            JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"
            AlignItems="Center"
            AlignContent="Center">
    <StackLayout x:Name="leftActionButton"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 BackgroundColor="Red"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="leftActionImg" 
               Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="leftActionLabel" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 BackgroundColor="Blue"
                 FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                 FlexLayout.Shrink="0">
        <Label x:Name="title"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="rightActionButton"
                 BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="rightActionLabel" 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        <Image x:Name="rightActionImg"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem recently. So I was investing a day to find a solution. The result is disillusioning and I wouldn't call it a proper solution. I'm posting my thoughts here, because I couldn't find anything similar on the net.

- I created a component which is responsible for balancing all three columns: It subscribes to width changes of the left and right column and propagates the relative difference to the center column.
- The center column takes the relative difference as correction by applying a padding.

**MainPage:** In the Resources part you see that I'm declaring an instance of ColumnBalancer. Later I subscribe Width changes to ColumnBalancer, so ColumnBalancer gets to known when the very left and very right column (content, actually) changes. The PaddingOffset binding is retrieved from the same ColumnBalancer instance whenever the Width values have changed.

```
   <ContentPage
        x:Class="App7863.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cb="clr-namespace:ColumnBalancing"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <cb:ColumnBalancer x:Key="ColumnBalancer" x:Name="ColumnBalancer" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--  Header  -->
            <Grid
                Grid.Row="0"
                Padding="10"
                BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="39" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--  Navigate Back Button  -->
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ColumnBalancer}, Path=ReferenceWidthLeft}"
                    Text="&lt;"
                    FontSize="20"
                    BackgroundColor="Magenta"
                    WidthRequest="39"
                    HeightRequest="39"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

                <!--  Page Title  -->
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="{Binding Source={x:Reference ColumnBalancer}, Path=PaddingOffset}"
                    BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
                    Spacing="0">
                    <Label
                        Text="Center Title"
                        FontSize="20"
                        BackgroundColor="Magenta"
                        HeightRequest="39"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                </StackLayout>

                <!--  Toolbar Items  -->
                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference ColumnBalancer}, Path=ReferenceWidthRight}"
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="0"
                    BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Spacing="6">
                    <Label
                        x:Name="ToolbarT1"
                        Text="T1"
                        FontSize="20"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        WidthRequest="39"
                        HeightRequest="39"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsVisible="False" />
                    <Label
                        x:Name="ToolbarT2"
                        Text="T2"
                        FontSize="20"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        WidthRequest="39"
                        HeightRequest="39"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        IsVisible="False" />
                </StackLayout>

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Text="Subtitle with more info"
                    FontSize="20"
                    BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                    HeightRequest="39"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            </Grid>

            <!--  Content  -->
            <Grid
                Grid.Row="1"
                Padding="40"
                BackgroundColor="LightCoral">
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
                    <Button Text="Toogle T1" Clicked="Button_ToogleT1" />
                    <Button Text="Toogle T2" Clicked="Button_ToogleT2" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage>
```

**ColumnBalancer:** Exposes a ReferenceWidthLeft and ReferenceWidthRight which take the Width values from the left resp. right column content. Whenever the ReferenceWidth* properties change, a new PaddingOffset is set.

```
 public class ColumnBalancer : BindableObject
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingOffsetProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(PaddingOffset),
                typeof(Thickness),
                typeof(ColumnBalancer),
                default(Thickness),
                BindingMode.OneWay);

            public Thickness PaddingOffset
            {
                get => (Thickness)this.GetValue(PaddingOffsetProperty);
                set => this.SetValue(PaddingOffsetProperty, value);
            }

            public static readonly BindableProperty ReferenceWidthRightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(ReferenceWidthRight),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(ColumnBalancer),
                default(double),
                BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
                null,
                OnReferenceWidthRightPropertyChanged);

            public double ReferenceWidthRight
            {
                get => (double)this.GetValue(ReferenceWidthRightProperty);
                set => this.SetValue(ReferenceWidthRightProperty, value);
            }

            public static readonly BindableProperty ReferenceWidthLeftProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(ReferenceWidthLeft),
                typeof(double),
                typeof(ColumnBalancer),
                default(double),
                BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
                null,
                OnReferenceWidthLeftPropertyChanged);

            public double ReferenceWidthLeft
            {
                get => (double)this.GetValue(ReferenceWidthLeftProperty);
                set => this.SetValue(ReferenceWidthLeftProperty, value);
            }

            private static void OnReferenceWidthLeftPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
            {
                if (!(bindable is ColumnBalancer columnBalancer) || !(newvalue is double newLeftValue && newLeftValue >= 0))
                {
                    return;
                }

                UpdatePaddingOffset(columnBalancer, newLeftValue, columnBalancer.ReferenceWidthRight);
            }

            private static void OnReferenceWidthRightPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
            {
                if (!(bindable is ColumnBalancer columnBalancer) || !(newvalue is double newRightValue && newRightValue >= 0))
                {
                    return;
                }

                UpdatePaddingOffset(columnBalancer, columnBalancer.ReferenceWidthLeft, newRightValue);
            }

            private static void UpdatePaddingOffset(ColumnBalancer columnBalancer, double left, double right)
            {
                if (left < 0)
                {
                    left = 0;
                }

                if (right < 0)
                {
                    right = 0;
                }

                var relativePadding = Math.Abs(left - right);
                if (right > left)
                {
                    columnBalancer.PaddingOffset = new Thickness(relativePadding, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    columnBalancer.PaddingOffset = new Thickness(0, 0, relativePadding, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using a 2-column grid and overlaying the "center" column on top by using `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`.

I realize this has the potential for the content in the center to overlap the content on the left and right, but I'm OK with working around this limitation if that's the best I can do. Still welcome other, more robust suggestions, though!

```
<Grid x:Name="titleBar" 
      MinimumHeightRequest="40"
      Padding="10"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackLayout x:Name="leftActionButton"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 HorizontalOptions="Start"
                 Grid.Column="0">
        <Image x:Name="leftActionImg" 
               Margin="0, 0, 5, 0"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label x:Name="leftActionLabel" 
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout x:Name="rightActionButton"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 HorizontalOptions="End"
                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                 Grid.Column="1">
        <Label x:Name="rightActionLabel" 
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        <Image x:Name="rightActionImg"
               HeightRequest="40"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Label x:Name="title"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: why you dont use three columns ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - I tried using 3 columns with `Width="*"`, but the middle column was too small, and I was having a hard time coming up with a "good enough" ratio of sizes for the three columns. I also tried the left and right columns with `Width="Auto"` and center with `Width="*"` but the `Grid` wasn't filling the whole screen. So in the end I settled on this approach which is working well so far.